# MaxRequestsPerChild equivalent for Jboss?

Tags: jboss, memory-leak

We have an application running on Jboss that's leaking memory and from to time to time, this causes the server to go into swap and crash.

I know the correct way to solve this is to find the root cause of the leakage, but at the moment I really need a workaround. As our number of requests are increasing, the outages are becoming somewhat frequent...

That said, do you know if there's a MaxRequestsPerChild equivalent for Jboss?

I work with the IT infrastructure and I'm not a developer nor a Java expert, so I can't sit and wait the developers fix the app (although I know they're working hard to do so) while my server goes down.

By the way, Jboss version is Jboss AS 4.0.5.

Comment: Which version of JBoss are you using?

Comment: Added on the question, @qweet

Answer (score 1):

In our environment, JBoss (both 4 and 5) uses threads rather than subprocesses to process queries so the question is irrelevant. If yours does fork, see docs/settings for the process pooler module used.

Comment: Very good point, @ivan_pozdeev. Indeed our JBoss uses threads instead of processes in order to respond to requests. So, should I assume a MaxRequestsPerChild equivalent in such scenario wouldn't help, since ending threads would not free up any memory managed by the main process?

Comment: Exactly. <padding>